# How to post data inside javascript variable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hello everyone I'm trying to post the data inside a JavaScript variable using AJAX, can anyone help me with the syntax?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">
        <div class="card-header py-3">



    <table class="table table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0" id="myTableData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
                <th>E</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>val1</td>
                <td>val2</td>
                <td>val3</td>
                <td>1500</td>
                <td>val5</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<script>
    init();
    function init(){

        addRowHandlers('myTableData');

    }

    function addRowHandlers(tableId) {
        if(document.getElementById(tableId)!=null){
            var table = document.getElementById(tableId);
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            var A = "";
            var B = "";
            var C = "";
            var D = "";
            function Registro(A, B, C, D, E) {
                            this.A = A;
                            this.B = B; 
                            this.C = C; 
                            this.D = D;
                            this.E = E;
                        };
            var total_registros = [];

            // Use let instead of var to avoid a closure arount the looping variable
            for ( let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {

                rows[i].i = i;
                rows[i].onclick = function() {
                    A = table.rows[this.i].cells[0].innerHTML;                
                    B = table.rows[this.i].cells[1].innerHTML;
                    C = table.rows[this.i].cells[2].innerHTML;
                    D = table.rows[this.i].cells[3].innerHTML;
                    E = table.rows[this.i].cells[4].innerHTML;
                    var newRegistro = new Registro(A, B, C, D, E);
                    total_registros.push(newRegistro);
                    console.log("-Log- New data", total_registros);
                    // Now remove the handler because the job is done
                    rows[i].onclick = null;
                };
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Currently, this grabs data and saves it inside total_registros[], how am I able to post this using AJAX?

```
<script>

    function seleccionar() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myURL',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'SYNTAX',
            contentType: 'application/SYNTAX',
            data: JSON.stringify(total_registros),
            success: function (response) {
                $('#').html(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

On success I just expect it to return a html response inside a the #div I declare

This data will be retrieved inside a [HttpPost] Controller in MVC

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View()
{
    return View();
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(total_registros)`

Comment: Edited question with your answer, thanks for the quick answer, do you know how can I retrieve this information in the controller? Btw will type : 'syntax' in the AJAX will be JSON? and contentType: 'application/SYNTAX', would be json instead of SYNTAX?

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali the data is not an object

Comment: @Chev using stringify would make it an object if I'm not wrong?
http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: @Chev JSON.stringify() doesn't care if it's an object, an array or even a boolean. It just turns it into a string that can be passed as a url query string for the controller to accept.

Comment: Yes, "SYNTAX" should be "json" in those two places.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks sir, edited the question with your answer, I appreciate a lot everyone's help <3

Comment: Had a look at the `total_registros` and seems its an array of objects like `[{
    "A": "val1",
    "B": "val2",
    "C": "val3",
    "D": "1500",
    "E": "val5"
  },
  {
    "A": "val1",
    "B": "val2",
    "C": "val3",
    "D": "500",
    "E": "val5"
  }]`. If that data is correct, then change the contentType to `application/json` and possibly JSON.stringify the data - may actually not need to JSON.stringify

Comment: @IceeFrog it doesn't help to fix the issues in your question. This makes it difficult for other users to follow what the issue was, the chat history and the final answer. I have rolled back the edit to make it more clear for other users.

Comment: @Chev never thought about it that way, thought it was gonna speed up answers, but indeed, I should keep original question, thanks for the feedback I won't forget this :)

Comment: No prob bud, been away but will post a full answer for you including the MVC side

Comment: @Chev Thanks a lot sir, I appreciate your time, I'll be around crawling the web :)

Comment: @Dementic hey thanks for your answer, I'll take a look at it ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues to point out. Your sample data generated is an array of objects like the following:

```
[
   { A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: 1500, E: "val5" }, 
   { A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: 1500, E: "val5" }
]
```

This is a great format for `JSON` to be posted to the MVC API routes.

**MVC API:**

Create a `public class` that represents the data above:

```
public class MyModel {
    public string A { get; set; }

    public string B { get; set; }

    public string C { get; set; }

    public int D { get; set; }

    public string E { get; set; }
}
```

Create routes to accept your post. I have shown two examples here - one to add a single object and one for an array of objects:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddModel ([FromBody] MyModel model) {
        // process the model
        ... 

        return Json (model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AddModels ([FromBody] IList<MyModel> models) {
        // process the list of models
        ...

        return Json (models);
    }
```

The parameter of type `MyModel` specified will use binding to convert the `JSON` into an instance of `MyModel` for you.

**Finally, update the JavaScript:**

Change the options to post JSON by updating the content type to `application/json` then and `stringify`'ing the data:

```
// posting a single model
let data = JSON.stringify({ A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: 1500, E: "val5" });
$.ajax({
    url: '/AddModel',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.info(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});

// posting a multiple models
data = JSON.stringify([{ A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: 1500, E: "val5" }, { A: "val1", B: "val2", C: "val3", D: 1500, E: "val5" }]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/AddModels',
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        console.info(response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does the [FromBody] mean? I can't put the pieces together sorry :(